# Polymer Elements don't work with latest GWT2.8 SNAPSHOT

Tags: gwt, maven-3, polymer-1.0

The latest GWT 2.8 SNAPSHOT seems to have removed support for the 
-XjsInteropMode flag. It's been known for a while that this would happen. The new flag is 
-generateJsInteropExports. But, Polymer doesn't seem to recognize this. I get a whole bunch of:

```
[INFO]          [ERROR] Errors in 'jar:file:/C:/Users/ntroncoso/.m2/repository/com/vaadin/polymer/vaadin-gwt-polymer-elements/1.2.1.0/vaadin-gwt-polymer-elements-1.2.1.0.jar!/com/vaadin/polymer/iron/event/IronActivateEvent.java'
[INFO]             [ERROR] Line 36: JsProperty cannot be resolved to a type
[INFO]             [ERROR] Line 31: JsProperty cannot be resolved to a type
[INFO]             [ERROR] Line 16: JsType cannot be resolved to a type
[INFO]             [ERROR] Line 22: JsProperty cannot be resolved to a type
[INFO]             [ERROR] Line 25: JsType cannot be resolved to a type
[INFO]             [ERROR] Line 11: The import com.google.gwt.core.client.js cannot be resolved
[INFO]             [ERROR] Line 10: The import com.google.gwt.core.client.js cannot be resolved
```

After replacing the flag. Is there anything else I need to do for Polymer to find the jsInterop stuff?

This change is inevitable, so saying to switch to 2.7 or an older 2.8 version isn't a proper solution, unless I simply have to wait for Vaadin to update their end. Is there a polymer snapshot repo available?

Comment: If you don't want to revert to an older GWT, then you have to wait for a newer GWT-Polymer-Elements. It looks like there are snapshots at Sonatype OSSRH, last one dated today.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

After digging some more, I was able to find a temporary solution, via:

https://github.com/vaadin/gwt-polymer-elements/issues/74

Using the frozen snapshot from manalo, my project builds. You need to add this to the maven settings.xml:

```
<repository>
    <id>gwt-snapshots-tmp-repo</id>
    <url>https://github.com/manolo/gwt-snapshot/raw/master/</url>
    <snapshots><enabled>true</enabled></snapshots>
    <releases><enabled>true</enabled></releases>
</repository>
```

And change your GWT version to 2.8.0.VC-SNAPSHOT.

According to this issues:

https://github.com/vaadin/gwt-polymer-elements/issues/66

https://github.com/vaadin/gwt-polymer-elements/issues/86

There is an impending gwt-polymer-elements release to address this issue.

Comment: …and it's now live: [1.2.3.0](https://github.com/vaadin/gwt-polymer-elements/releases/tag/vaadin-gwt-polymer-elements-1.2.3.0)

Answer (score 0):

In my case the error came while trying to use the vaadin polymer wrapper version 1.2.3.0 with gwt 2.7.

Even with the jsInterOp set to JS, compilation did no work.

Switching to gwt 2.8.0-beta1, the gwt:compile task finally managed to  process the:
import jsinterop.annotations.JsType

in the com.vaadin.polymer.paper elements.

Check the compatibility between you gwt version, namely the compiler, and the web components library.